# PowerApps Custom connector dependent dropdown swagger

Tags: powerapps, power-apps-custom-connector

I've a custom connector with one API call
**Situation in flows**
I want to fill dropdown based on another dropdown selected value by user
**ex.**

- Country dropdown
- State dropdown

  I want to fill State dropdown based on Country dropdown's selected value. I get my success to fill Country dynamic dropdown, but not State dropdown.

```
    {
      "swagger": "2.0",
      "info": {
        "title": "test",
        "description": "",
        "version": "1.0"
      },
      "host": "test-api.azurewebsites.net",
      "basePath": "/",
      "schemes": [
        "https"
      ],
      "consumes": [],
      "produces": [],
      "paths": {
        "/api/values/GetCountry": {
          "get": {
            "responses": {
              "default": {
                "description": "default",
                "schema": {}
              }
            },
            "summary": "GetCountry",
            "description": "GetCountry",
            "operationId": "GetCountry",
            "parameters": []
          }
        },
        "/api/Values/UpdateData": {
          "patch": {
            "responses": {
              "default": {
                "description": "default",
                "schema": {}
              }
            },
            "summary": "UpdateData",
            "description": "UpdateData",
            "operationId": "UpdateData",
            "parameters": [
              {
                "name": "body",
                "in": "body",
                "required": false,
                "schema": {
                  "type": "object",
                  "properties": {
                    "Country": {
                      "type": "string",
                      "description": "Select country",
                      "x-ms-dynamic-values": {
                        "operationId": "GetCountry",
                        "value-path": "countryid",
                        "value-title": "countryname"
                      },
                      "title": "Country"
                    },
                    "State": {
                      "type": "string",
                      "description": "Select state",
                      "x-ms-dynamic-values": {
                        "operationId": "GetState",
                        "value-path": "stateid",
                        "value-title": "statename",
                        "parameters": {
                          "countryid": "91"
                        }
                      },
                      "title": "State"
                    },
                    "State Date": {
                      "type": "string",
                      "description": "State Date"
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        "/api/values/GetState": {
          "get": {
            "responses": {
              "default": {
                "description": "default",
                "schema": {}
              }
            },
            "summary": "GetState",
            "description": "GetState",
            "operationId": "GetState",
            "parameters": [
              {
                "name": "countryid",
                "in": "query",
                "required": true,
                "type": "string"
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      "definitions": {},
      "parameters": {},
      "responses": {},
      "securityDefinitions": {},
      "security": [],
      "tags": []
    }
```

*countryid* which I passed static 91, I need that dynamic, whatever user selects in country dropdown.
[image]